# QWidget seems to ignore event passed by EventFilter

Tags: qt, qt5

I got a problem when trying to pass events with the QT eventFilter.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
if(event->type() == QEvent::Wheel){
    QPoint pos = QCursor::pos();
    QWidget *widget = QApplication::widgetAt(pos);
        if(widget != NULL){
            widget->setVisible(false); //for Test purposes only
            qDebug() << widget; //also for test 
            QApplication::sendEvent(widget, event); //should send event to widget?
                return true;
            }

                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

I want to catch the scrolling of the Mouse-wheel and pass it to multiple QWidgets at once. If I execute the above without the sendEvent the widget i want to attend will disappear (thats what i kinda want for the test). If i use the sendEvent, nothing happens OR it crashes with an segmentation fault error... I tried anything i found online (or I at least think so)..

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you send the event to the widget, you'll end up in an infinite recursion, because the event filter will intercept it again. Just return `false` if you want the widget to receive the event, or `true` if you want to stop event propagation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `QApplication::sendEvent(widget, event);` and if `widget` is a child of `MainWindow` or itself, the receiving event will be filtered again in `MainWindow::eventFilter`. It creates a recursive infinite loop.
I added a flag `sendingEvent` to `return true;` if event is sending. Hope that can help.

```
bool MyWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){

    if (event->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
    {
        static bool sendingEvent = false;
        if (sendingEvent)
        {
            //exit recursive call, return false to avoid swallowing the event
            return false;
        }
        QPoint pos = QCursor::pos();
        QWidget *widget = QApplication::widgetAt(pos);
        if (widget != NULL){
            qDebug() << widget; //also for test         

            //set the flag before sending event
            sendingEvent = true;

            QApplication::sendEvent(widget, event); //should send event to widget?

            //reset the flag after sending event
            sendingEvent = false;
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was already wondering why the qDebug output listed so many items. I also guess that this will fix the crashes! But the event still seems not to get passed to the Widget... It's a QCustomPlot which should zoom in while scrolling. (it does work when i directly return false at the event Filter, so the handling the Event on the widget site should not be the problem).

Comment: Sorry, I returned true to exit recursive call cause it swallows the event. Updated to `return false;` already.

Comment: Glad to hear that!